# How do I restore sources that are ignored on upgrade?

Tags: 10.10, server, apt, repository, software-sources

When I upgraded my server to 10.10, some of my sources (basically hudson and git) are now being ignored... any idea how I can get them active again? The entries are in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, but the status line on apt-get update says

`Ign http://hudson-ci.org binary/ Packages`

Comment: Please add the contents of the sources.list entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this apt line is no more valid for maverick (10.10) version and it was only available for lucid (10.04).

Comment: Yeah, turns out they changed the repo for maverick, so had to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a *Hit* line after the *Ign* one all should be OK.

Ign lines appear because newer versions of apt-get try to get the package list in .bz2 format first. If it fails, it will try to load the old format and report a Hit if it success or and Err if it fails.